# Javascript: Stop mouse-move events if a certain key is pressed

Tags: javascript, events

I need to stop mouse-movement events if a certain key is pressed, can this be done using JavaScript?

```
window.addEventListener("mousemove", stopMovement, false)
function stopMovement(key){
    if(key.keyCode == 71){ //G key
        event.preventDefault()
    }
}
```

Comment: What you want is to make your mousemove event **handler** to not fire when the key is pressed. So just set up a variable that will act as a flag, and raise it (set it to true) when the key is pressed. Then in your mousemove handler just check if your variable is true, then return early, otherwise handle the mouse event. If you really have a good use-case where you can't do this, then include it as an [edit] to your question, because *There-are-always-hacks™*)

Comment: I dont have access to the site's code which calls the mousemove event